# Would those 'trapped' in a collapsing universe perceive space as expanding?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes

Let's say we have Uber Massif; a black hole so mindbogglingly huge, if you where to shrink the entire milkyway into a thimble Uber Massif would be the size of the milkyway.  Those proportions need not be strictly adhered; I just want to illustrate the idea.  Anyhoo, lets assume some conga-line of galaxies slipping into Uber Massif's event horizon; antecedents should always be accelerating faster than their successors, correct?  If so, this would give their 'local' space the appearance of expanding.  How would this model differ from what is currently observed?

Answer (score 3):

It would **not** give the impression the universe was expanding.

The expansion of the universe is related to the [Ricci tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature) and scalar. For a black hole of the type you describe the Ricci tensor and scalar are both zero. If you mark out any volume of space and watch it then its volume will not increase with time.

However in the black hole geometry the [Weyl tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_tensor) is non-zero, which means that tidal forces are present. The observers in your string of galaxies would observe space expanding in the direction of the centre of the black hole but contracting in directions at 90º to this. The expansion and contraction balance out so the net volume change is zero.

The result is that the galaxies would be stretched out into a long thin shape in the process known as [spaghettification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification).

Comment: So this 'contraction' of perpendicular dimensions - might they be describable as a rotation?  Like, take a simple line segment rotated in a 2d coordinate system will 'shrink' along one axis while expand along another if it rotates it about its center.  would this spaghettification be analogous to a three dimensional object 'rotating' in four dimensions?

Comment: @punkerplunk: no. There is no rotational motion.

Comment: i mean as a model.  An analogy.  I'm asking if the same equation would describe these separate events.  or, more specifically, how would rotation be different from following the curvature of the field about a singularity.

Comment: @punkerplunk: no, not even as a model. I can't see how you could usefully use rotation in this context. Don't be mislead by the term *curvature* - nothing is rotating around a curve.